# Derive Chernoff bounds for complementary CDF of X ~ Poisson

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-distribution

My lecture notes have the following derivation of the Chernoff bounds for the complementary CDF of a random variable X, that is Poisson with mean $\alpha$.

The Poisson MGF is

$$M_X(s) = exp[\alpha(e^s - 1)]$$
and hence
$$e^{-sx}M_X(s) = exp[\alpha e^s - \alpha - sx]$$
We define the logarithm of the last expression as 
$$h(s) = \alpha e^s - \alpha - sx$$
Setting the derivative of $h(s)$ to zero yields
$$h'(s) = \alpha e^s - x$$
$$s = ln\frac{x}{\alpha}$$
It is obvious that $h''(s)>0$ for all s, and hence the minimum of $h(s)$ in the range $s>0$ is found at $s = ln\frac{x}{\alpha}$ which is positive when $x>\alpha$, and at $s = 0$ when $x \le \alpha$.

After some simplications, we get the Chernoff bound as 
$$P(X \ge x) \le \begin{cases}e^{x-\alpha}\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)^x, x > \alpha \\e^{-\alpha}, x \le \alpha\end{cases}$$

I have 2 questions.

(1) I can't get the bound when $x \le \alpha$, that is $e^{-\alpha}$. Instead, I got $e^{\alpha e^0 - \alpha - 0} = e^0 = 1$. Didn't we get this from substituting s = 0 into $e^{-sx}M_X(s)$?

(2) I understand that to find the Chernoff bound, we have to minimize $e^{-sx}M_X(s)$ over all positive s. But why do we need to find $s=0$? Furthermore, isn't $s = 0$ at $x = \alpha$ only? Why is $s=0$ when $x \ge \alpha$?

Comment: The bound in (1) should read $1$, not $e^{-\alpha}$ (which is wrong for $x=0$, say). Re (2), one does not "find $s=0$", one chooses $s$ such that $h'(s)=0$, to minimize $h(s)$ (and this $s$ is zero for no $x>\alpha$).

Comment: But I thought $h(s)$ is minimized over $s>0$. Doesn't choosing $s=0$ contradict this? And when $x \le \alpha$, doesn't that make $s \le 0$?

Comment: Yes $h(s)$ is minimized over $s>0$. And the function $h$ is decreasing on $[0,s^*]$ then increasing on $[s^*,+\infty)$ for some $s^*>0$, which is why one uses $h(s^*)<0$ and not $h(0)=0$ to get a nontrivial upper bound of $P(X\geqslant x)$ when $x>\alpha$. To repeat: one does not choose $s=0$ when $x>\alpha$.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand... So do we consider when $s = 0$ or not? I don't understand why we consider $x \le \alpha$. Is it just for completeness sake to cover the whole range of x?

Comment: Yeah, and reading *carefully* and *slowly* what I wrote would be a good start.